# PHP Dom Is there any way an element can create an element

Tags: php, dom

I realize that createElement() is a DOMDocument method.

If I have methods to which an element is passed, in this case, for a subsequent

```
element::parent::insertBefore(new_element, element)
```

is there a way given only the element to refer to the DomDocument so that the element can be created, an equivalent of

```
element::document::createElement()
```

or do I always need to pass the it as an additional parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$element->ownerDocument->createElement(...)
```

inherited from `\DOMNode`

Reference: https://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.ownerdocument